# ListView not notified of Adapter Change

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Logcat:

```
06-28 22:21:11.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ArrayAdapter)]
```

Code:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {          
        items.add(NewItem);
        Collections.sort(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Question: Where am I suppose to update ListView also?

Comment: post your doInBackground method code here. You can update listview in onPostExecute only. I have posted below my code which works perfect

Comment: Your code was all I needed.  Perfect!

Comment: I did. Was waiting for elapsed time to pass.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            arrayCountries = objwscountry.CountryCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }



@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(arrayCountries);
        // apply the Adapter:
        spinCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

See this code works perfect.